# Grouping Ages in panda

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group an age column into various groups. The groups are

```
(“Children”: 0-14 years; “Youth”: 15-24 years; “Adults”: 25-65 years; “Seniors”: 65 +)
```

I did try using panda cut but it seems like my bin values are way more than the labels, here's my code so far

```
bins = [0,14,15,24,25,65]
category_names = ['Children', 'Youth', 'Adults', 'Seniors', np.inf]
df3['AgeGroup'] = pd.cut(df3['Age'], bins=bins, labels=category_names)
```

Help is appreciated, ty

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: you gave 6 cutoffs for 4 bins. Revisit the documentation on how to specify those partition values. You need to eliminate the superfluous ones, likely 14 and 24. Also note that 0 is superfluous, unless you're making a category for pre-borns.

You have 4 categories; this mandates 3 partition values.

```
bins = [0,15,25,65]
category_names = ['Children', 'Youth', 'Adults', 'Seniors']
```

Note also that I've removed the inapplicable "infinity" value from your list of string labels.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick, had to add 100 after 65 to have 5 bin values to satisfy the condition.

Comment: Ah, right -- *that* is where your infinity value could go.  My mistake -- I used to test and help maintain an interface that required n-1 partitions.